# Timeseries denoising and downsampling

Tags: time-series, noise-reduction, downsampling

What are some different denoising techniques for time series? What conditions have to be in place to downsample a time series without loss of information?

Comment: this is not a question for SO

Answer (score 0):

depends on which kind of time-series data you want to denoise as denoising can be pretty different from sector to sector.
Like, for denoising audio data in the time domain you can use the webRTC noise cancelation module or apply a noise cancelation algorithm (lots of these are out there) to your audio.